# Python while loop, I'm stuck help! :C

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop

I'm new to programming (just started 3 days ago) and I need help with this code, I really do.

I don't know how to do the `while` loop. (below the `####` line). Can you help me?

I'm using `python` version 3.4.2

```
import random

right = 0
wrong = 0

for i in range(10):

        x = random.randint (2,29)
        y = random.randint (3,29)
        z = (x*y)
        qq = input("What's " + str(x) + " times " + str(y) + "? ")


        if   str(z) == str(qq):
             right = right +1
             print ("Correct!\n")

        else:
            wrong = wrong + 1
            print ("Wrong the correct answer is ",str(z),"\n")


print ("You got", right, "out of 10 questions")

if right==10:
        print ("Well Done! Perfect score!")

elif right>=5:
        print ("Well done! try getting perfect score next time")

else:
        print ("Noob")
#################################################
restart = y
while True:
        yess = input ("Would you like to try again? y/n?")
        if restart == yess:
                print (i)
        else:
                break
```

Comment: you just need to put your entire code into the while loop so it actually repeats

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the quick fix for that problem:

```
import random

while True:    
    right = 0
    wrong = 0

    for i in range(10):

            x = random.randint (2,29)
            y = random.randint (3,29)
            z = (x*y)
            qq = input("What's " + str(x) + " times " + str(y) + "? ")


            if   str(z) == str(qq):
                 right = right +1
                 print ("Correct!\n")

            else:
                wrong = wrong + 1
                print ("Wrong the correct answer is ",str(z),"\n")


    print ("You got", right, "out of 10 questions")

    if right==10:
            print ("Well Done! Perfect score!")

    elif right>=5:
            print ("Well done! try getting perfect score next time")

    else:
            print ("Noob")
    #################################################
    restart = "y"
    yess = input ("Would you like to try again? y/n?")
    if restart != yess:
        break;
```

Essentially, you just need to put your entire code into the while loop so it actually repeats.

Also, I honestly hope I didn't mess up when I put the `"y"` in quotation marks to make it a string. I haven't touched Python for more than an hour, so I'm hazy on the syntax.

Comment: OMG YOU'RE A LEGEND, i see i kinda get it now :P thank you so much!.. so if  i want my code to keep repeating i just have to put everything in while loop ryt?

Comment: Pretty much, but always make sure there is a way to exit it so that it won't be an infinite loop with no means to terminate it (unless that really is what you need). What you write down is what happens, and everything is interpreted line by line (especially in Python), after all :)